# Solving a java program with big input size in Top coder

Tags: java

I'm solving a problem from SRM 144 DIV 1 in java. My code work with all the test cases but there is a test case with value "12221112222221112221111111112221111"
now i know that this exceeds limit of any data type in java.

Now is there is a way to solve this.
Here is the sample of my code.

```
public class BinaryCode{
public String[] decode(String message){
    int mess = Integer.parseInt(message);
    int encmess[] = new int[message.length()];
    for(int i = message.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        encmess[i] = mess%10;
        mess = mess/10;
    }
    int[] decmess1 = new int[message.length()];
    int[] decmess2 = new int[message.length()];
    decmess1[0] = 0;
    decmess2[0] = 1;
    String mess1 = "";
    String mess2 = "";

    for(int i = 1;i<decmess1.length;i++){
        if(i == 1){
            decmess1[i] = encmess[i-1] - decmess1[i-1];
        }
        else{
            decmess1[i] = encmess[i-1] - decmess1[i-1] - decmess1[i-2];
        }
        if(decmess1[i]>1||decmess1[i]<0){
            mess1 = "NONE";
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1;i<decmess2.length;i++){
        if(i == 1){
            decmess2[i] = encmess[i-1] - decmess2[i-1];
        }
        else{
            decmess2[i] = encmess[i-1] - decmess2[i-1] - decmess2[i-2];
        }
        if(decmess2[i]>1||decmess2[i]<0){
            mess2 = "NONE";
            break;
        }
    }
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    if(!mess1.equals("NONE")){
        for(int i = 0;i<decmess2.length;i++){

                num1 = num1*10 + decmess1[i];

        }
    }
    if(!mess2.equals("NONE")){
        for(int i = 0;i<decmess2.length;i++){

            num2 = num2*10 + decmess2[i];
        }
    }
    if(!mess1.equals("NONE"))
        mess1 = "0"+Integer.toString(num1);
    if(!mess2.equals("NONE"))
        mess2 = Integer.toString(num2);

    String[] result = {mess1,mess2};
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `BigInteger` instead of `int`

Try something like that

```
BigInteger mess = new BigInteger(message);
```

Comment: But then i don't think I can do arithmetic between a BigInteger and an int  because i get error.

Comment: There are methods to do arithmetic operation in BigInteger class. e.g. instead of ``+`` you need to use ``add()``method

Comment: ``BigInteger`` definitely solve your problem. Plz read more details about BigInteger. then your like will be easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) has *arbitrary-precision*. Your existing method could be altered to something like

```
public static String[] decode(String message) {
    BigInteger TEN = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    BigInteger mess = new BigInteger(message);
    BigInteger encmess[] = new BigInteger[message.length()];
    for (int i = message.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        encmess[i] = mess.mod(TEN);
        mess = mess.divide(TEN);
    }
    BigInteger[] decmess1 = new BigInteger[message.length()];
    BigInteger[] decmess2 = new BigInteger[message.length()];
    decmess1[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    decmess2[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
    String mess1 = "";
    String mess2 = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < decmess1.length; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            decmess1[i] = encmess[i - 1].subtract(decmess1[i - 1]);
        } else {
            decmess1[i] = encmess[i - 1].subtract(decmess1[i - 1])//
                    .subtract(decmess1[i - 2]);
        }
        if (decmess1[i].compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 //
                || decmess1[i].compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
            mess1 = "NONE";
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < decmess2.length; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            decmess2[i] = encmess[i - 1].subtract(decmess2[i - 1]);
        } else {
            decmess2[i] = encmess[i - 1].subtract(decmess2[i - 1])//
                    .subtract(decmess2[i - 2]);
        }
        if (decmess2[i].compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 //
                || decmess2[i].compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
            mess2 = "NONE";
            break;
        }
    }
    BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.ZERO, num2 = BigInteger.ZERO;
    if (!mess1.equals("NONE")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < decmess2.length; i++) {
            num1 = num1.multiply(TEN).add(decmess1[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!mess2.equals("NONE")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < decmess2.length; i++) {
            num2 = num2.multiply(TEN).add(decmess2[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!mess1.equals("NONE"))
        mess1 = "0" + num1.toString();
    if (!mess2.equals("NONE"))
        mess2 = num2.toString();

    String[] result = { mess1, mess2 };
    return result;
}
```

Then you could call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decode("12221112222221112221111111112221111")));
}
```

And I get

```
[01101001101101001101001001001101001, 10110010110110010110010010010110010]
```

Comment: Yeah that works but I still don't understand why do I've have to use BigInteger after first loops. I mean why did you make decmess1 and decmess2 BigInteger

Comment: Because adding (or subtracting) two `BigInteger`(s) results in a `BigInteger`.

Comment: Yeah but can't I do this                                                                 encmess[i] = mess.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(10)).intValue(); it will give me int value and then I can work with int.